# Refresh a single part of a webpage without passing parameters

Tags: php, multilingual, partial-page-refresh

I'm developping a web application in PHP and I would like to refresh a single part of my application. I found some post which explains how to do that with some parameters passing into the URLlike follow:

index.php:

```
if ((isset($_GET['page'])) && (isset($authorizedPage[$_GET['page']]))) {
    require_once ($authorizedPage[$_GET['page']]);
} else {
    require_once ('./home.php');
}
```

So the URL http://example.com/index.php?page=login **will display my login page** without reloading my index.php... it's ok so far.

But my problem is more how to have the same behavior without passing parameter in the URL. Meaning that if I would like display the login page I will have the following URL http://example.com/login/

Could you help me please ?

For your information in the future, I will need to integrate the notion of multilingual website.

Thanks

Comment: Use `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: you can use it without problem..

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't see how I will use POST in my anchor which will call [http://XXXXXX.com/login/] or  [http://XXXXXX.com/home/] or [http://XXXXXX.com/anotherPage/]

Comment: Whatever you read, it obviously confused you. Read about ajax, jQuery, etc.

Comment: Maybe.. I'm just trying to learn PHP :) and unfortunately I am not familiar with this language. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to change the way people load pages on your website, don't you? So that people can load pages like example.com/login/ and example.com/faq/ instead of example.com?page=login and example.com?page=faq.

You should use the mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file in the root of you server. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for documentation.

I use the code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ index.php?0=$1&1=$2&2=$3&3=$4&4=$5&5=$6&6=$7&7=$8&8=$9 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

in my .htaccess file to pass all the requests to my index.php file. Each folder in the url will be a GET parameter.

That's the first part of your problem. When you want to reload just a part of your webpage, use JQuery with AJAX, like Marek commented earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think it's a little bit complicated. But you are right, I want to change the way people load pages :D. Anyway, Is it a good pattern ?

Comment: See my next answer (comment would be too long)

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` line in my code is a good pattern and will load the index.php file when someone is loading my website. So if someone loads http://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/file, the file `index.php?0=folder1&1=folder2&3=file&4=&5=&6=&7=&8=&9=` will be loaded. Then in PHP you can switch on the $_GET parameters to load the right page:

```
<?php
    switch ($_GET['0']) {
        case 'faq':
            {code}
            break;

        case 'login':
            {code}
            break;

        default:
            {code of you home page}
            break;
    }
?>
```

You can paste my .htaccess file in a blank notepad, save it as ".htaccess" and store it in the root of you server. Should work directly.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's clear and helpfull. I will take a look to my provider to know if I can change the mod_rewrite.

Comment: You're welcome. Most hosting providers turns the mod_rewrite on by default. The line `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` checks for that and avoids errors. If it works, the mod_rewrite module is turned on, otherwise you should contact your provider.